# NSDictionary format

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Can anybody help me create an NSDictionary format of the following structure:

```
{
key1 = "value1";
    key2 = "value2";
    key3 =     [
                {
            key01 = "value01";
            key02 = "value02";
        },
                {
            key01 = "value01";
            key02 = "value02";
        },
                {
            key01 = "value01";
            key02 = "value02";
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: It is NSDictionary Format, what do you want to ask?

Comment: how do i code this json structure ?

Comment: Do you want to convert this to NSDictionary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer your question about converting that JSON data to NSDictionary, here it is:

*(assuming you already got your JSON data)*

```
// add the first 2 VALUES with it's KEYS
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mainDict setValue:VALUE1 forKey:KEY1];
[mainDict setValue:VALUE2 forKey:KEY2];

// then for the last KEY, create a mutable array where you will store your sub dictionaries
NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[subDict setValue:SUB_VALUE1 forKey:SUB_KEY1];
[subDict setValue:SUB_VALUE1 forKey:SUB_KEY2];
[ma addObject:subDict];

// then add that array to your main dictionary
[mainDict setValue:ma forKey:KEY3];

// check the output
NSLog(@"mainDict : %@", mainDict);
```

---

```
// SAMPLE DATA - Test this if this is what you want
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mainDict setValue:@"value1" forKey:@"key1"];
[mainDict setValue:@"value2" forKey:@"key2"];

NSMutableArray *ma = [NSMutableArray array];
NSMutableDictionary *subDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[subDict setValue:@"subValue1" forKey:@"subKey1"];
[subDict setValue:@"subValue2" forKey:@"subKey2"];
[ma addObject:subDict];

[mainDict setValue:ma forKey:@"key3"];

NSLog(@"mainDict : %@", mainDict);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this code it might help you.

```
NSDictionary *dicationary = @{
                                  @"key1":@"value1",
                                  @"key2":@"value2",
                                  @"key3":@[@{@"key01":@"value01",@"key02":@"value02"},
                                            @{@"key01":@"value01",@"key02":@"value02"},
                                            @{@"key01":@"value01",@"key02":@"value02"}]
                                  };
```

Comment: Formatting matters, it makes this code is ease to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

There is API in obj-c to convert Json to nsdictionary .I guess you should try that  :

1. First convert json to nsdata (assuming you above JSON is in string format)

2.Then you API to convert that to NSDictionary :

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
NSString *jsonString = @"{\"ID\":{\"Content\":268,\"type\":\"text\"}}";
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonDict[@"ID"][@"Content"]);
```

Will return you:
268